# RDL report to show sort selection

Tags: c#, reporting-services

Is there any way I can print the sorting option in a text box?  For example, if my table has a "Status" column and I chose to sort by "Status", then I can print the word "Status" in a text box.  This is the RDL report.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this is what you're trying to achieve?

1. Indicate parameter sort option with default values:

[image]

[image]

2. Then create a textbox and simply drag the parameter inside the textbox that should look like this:
   [image]
3. Then when you try to preview the report and select a sort option, something like below should appear:
   [image]

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I already have a 1 parameter, if I create a new "SortOption" parameter, my report doesn't work.  What I want to archive is when I click on the little arrow up/down in "Status" column, I can see the header text "Status" in a different texbox.  Is it possible?  Thank you all for answering.

Comment: Haha..thats cool..ill try if I can see this working..im having a feeling this have to pass through expressions..also what BiDS visual studio are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010.  I am trying to do a workaround like to change the background color of a header if the column is sorted...maybe it is more archivable?!!

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using a parameterized report where the sorting can change simply capture the the parameter in a text box or often what I do is create another dataset that is

```
Select @parameter1
Union select @parameter2
Union Select @parameterN
```

Then display that in another tablix (or cell depending on how many you have)